# C++ - Poco library in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, poco-libraries

I am trying to use the poco library in Qt Creator with one of the samples that came with poco, I have gotten this to work in Visual Studio 2012 but I keep getting build errors in Qt Creator.
I have both .dll and .lib in my lib path.

here is my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\justin\Downloads\poco-1.4.6\Net\include
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Users\justin\Downloads\poco-1.4.6\Foundation\include

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lPocoFoundation
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lPocoFoundationd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/PocoFoundation.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/PocoFoundationd.lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lPocoNet
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lPocoNetd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/PocoNet.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/PocoNetd.lib
```

and here is the .cpp file

```
#include "Poco/URIStreamOpener.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include "Poco/Path.h"
#include "Poco/URI.h"
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPStreamFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Net/FTPStreamFactory.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


using Poco::URIStreamOpener;
using Poco::StreamCopier;
using Poco::Path;
using Poco::URI;
using Poco::Exception;
using Poco::Net::HTTPStreamFactory;
using Poco::Net::FTPStreamFactory;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HTTPStreamFactory::registerFactory();
    FTPStreamFactory::registerFactory();



    try
    {
        URI uri("http://example.com");
        std::auto_ptr<std::istream> pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri));
        StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), std::cout);
    }
    catch (Exception& exc)
    {
        std::cerr << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and these are the build errors:

```
undefined reference to `Poco::Net::HTTPStreamFactory::registerFactory()'
undefined reference to `Poco::Net::FTPStreamFactory::registerFactory()'
undefined reference to `Poco::URI::URI(char const*)'
undefined reference to `Poco::URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener()'
undefined reference to `Poco::URIStreamOpener::open(Poco::URI const&) const'
undefined reference to `Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(std::istream&, std::ostream&, unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `Poco::URI::~URI()'
undefined reference to `Poco::URI::~URI()'
```

Comment: Are you using MSVC2012 in Qtcreator, or mingw? You cannot use C++ libraries compiled with msvc together with mingw and vice-versa. Also that qmake logic looks a bit weird: I'd suggest win32 { CONFIG( ... ) { ... } else { ... } }. The PRE_TARGETDEPS should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The same compiler must be used to compile all three of the below:

1. Poco library
2. Qt library
3. Your application

My hunch is that you use MSVC2012 for #3, you correctly downloaded #2 for MSVC2012, but you did not compile #1 with MSVC2012.